# Freezing gridview header in a fixed width div

Tags: gridview

I have seen some gridview header freezing examples on the web but I have a special case where the gridview is in a fixed width div. The examples I tried make the header fixed but the full width of the header is shown and it overflows out of the div while the grid body has a horizontal scroll bar.

I need it to:
1- Header and tbody scroll together horizontally and both confined in the fixed width div.
2- Header is fixed while gridview body scrolls vertically.
3- Don't want to use a commercial grid.
4- I am using IE only. Don't care if it works in FF, Opera, ..etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a jQuery plugin that does exactly what you need. You just build 1 table with a thead and tbody and it does the rest for you. Very simple to use...i posted the solution under another question linked below.  Supported in IE6/7/8 too.

[Frozen table header inside scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486576/frozen-table-header-inside-scrollable-div/1533619#1533619)

or a link straight to my plugin site:

http://fixedheadertable.mmalek.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this example?
http://web.tampabay.rr.com/bmerkey/examples/locked-column-csv.html