# Scrolling table, keep header fixed

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, scroll

I would like my table header to be fixed when I scroll vertically.

Also, how do I make my table stay inside the tab contents of jQuery UI Tabs? I want it to be aligned against the bottom of it; it's not supposed to be 100% of the tab content height because there is other content above the table, but I want it to fill out all the available space (the tabs are of certain height to not go below screen, so the body is not supposed to have a scroll bar, nor the tabs). As you can see today, I have a fixed table height of 450px, and on some screens that's perfect but on some it goes outside (see picture).

[image]

I want the scrollbar to be on the very right hand side (the yellow line), not next to where the table ends, if possible. Similar to Facebook I think.

Comment: Would be better if you can provide the code sample that you have. **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)** or **[jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/)**

Comment: A very tedious way of doing that: http://jsfiddle.net/PfGQA/

Comment: take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on)

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions I've found met all my requirements, so I created a very lightweight jQuery plugin to do this.  It supports fixed header, footer, column spanning (colspan), resizing, and an optional number of rows to display before scrolling starts.

[jQuery.scrollTableBody (GitHub)](https://github.com/nheldman/jquery.scrollTableBody)

As long as you have a table with proper `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and (optional) `<tfoot>`, all you need to do is this:

```
$('table').scrollTableBody();
```

**UPDATE:**  Added support for horizontal scrolling as well

Comment: +1. I really liked what you did. can you please add a vertical scrolling functionality to your lib?

Comment: @avrahamcool Thanks... did you mean horizontal scrolling?  If so, I'll take a look at adding that.

Comment: @avrahamcool I've added support for horizontal scrolling (GitHub updated)

Comment: @avrahamcool I've updated the examples on GitHub to include a bit more info, and divs to wrap the table.  Please try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: I just tried it now. and I'm experimenting some issues, can we take this conversation to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38362/scrolltablebody)?

Comment: I've fixed the horizontal scrolling issues in Firefox and IE, let me know if you see any other issues, thanks.

Comment: Works great.. can you add an option to specify the number of column to initially show?