# How to create a table with a fixed column and 3 scrollable parts

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

How would I create an HTML table that looks like the picture?
In my case I have many fields, and I want to show the important ones with fixed column and show the other detail with scrollable bar,
just look at this picture:

[image: picture]

I have found this link https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html
But this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to the CSS file, to whatever class your using for those table cells...

```
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

See more CSS Overflow handling at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: with overflow i just can make one part scrollable table, unlike the picture that i show above (it has 3 scrollable part)

Comment: You need to assign a CSS *class* to the table cells that you want to behave this way.. something like `<td class="sidescroll"`   then the CSS for `.sidescroll`  would contain the 2 lines I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Datatables and to make some cells have scroll bars is already answered at this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566378/how-to-make-the-some-columns-fixed-and-some-scrollable-of-a-table)

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with jQuery Datatable and Fixed cols and horizontal bar on some cell: 
    `jsfiddle`[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2x8W/)
Credit of this goes to @davidkonrad from that post linked above.

Comment: i do using dataTable and this is my datatable code like this http://imgur.com/a/Lh3Te
the link that you gave me is similiar to what i want to build, but i cant make it like the picture (its like having 4 table in 1 table)