# How to fix position of table row

Tags: html, position, fixed

This is my first post, so I hope I am asking the right way.
I have a page with a large table. When I scroll down I would like the top row to stay fixed. I have tried writing the code and put the result up [here](http://www.rankfootball.com/test.html).
The problem is that for some reason the width is not the same as the width of the rest of the table. And Also it is transparent so you can see the text under it at the same time. The table looks fine on my other pages on that site where I have not tried to fix it, but I would like to make it easier for my viewers and would appreciate your help as I still consider myself a novice.

Comment: the width of what is not the same as the width of the rest of the table? I'd suggest to create a jsFiddle instead of giving a link to a site. Make sure you've made a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed header table with horizontal scrollbar and vertical scrollbar on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on)

Answer (score 0):

try fixing the table on top, in css with

position: fixed;