# How to align table with fixed columns and table with content beside each other

Tags: html, css, angular

I know there are hundred of postings here about fixed columns, horizontal scrolling in tables - but most of them don't work for me or they have some constraints which don't allow me to use it. I tried to resolve the problem has one table which contains all frozen columns and I wanted to have a second table beside which has the scrollable columns. But even after hours, I don't get this working. I played around with many solutions - nested tables, containers - no success. I tried float left/right - but the issue is that my table is obviously too big and therefore will always float below.

So all that I want to achieve: Have a table on the left side with all frozen columns - have a table beside with the content and which can scroll horizontally. How can I wrap my 2 tables to achieve this?

I am using `Angular` - so I want to do this with pure `HTML/CSS/Angular`. I also cannot use some of the existing modules since this is part of a more complex solution.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: do you have any code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the part of your table into one div and the scrollable one in another. On the scrollable div container you set a width or max-width and apply overflow-x: scroll or auto. This way one part will be fixed, the other will scroll.

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
  //your fixed part of table here
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
  //your scrollable part of table here
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.scrollable {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Demo plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/oMlaQHebzf8Uk9dITpqm?p=preview)

**Edit**

For vertical scroll you only have to limit the height of the container also and set overflow-x to scroll or, given the fact that you have both on your container, just overflow: scroll or auto.

```
.scrollable{
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

You have a working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TPr2Gsep3aywEV7QLz6V?p=preview)

If you want to add the sticky header is a bit more complicated, take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932179)

Comment: Hi this works! Thank you!

Do you also have a sample where vertical+ horizontal scrolling are working and where I can fix the header row?

Comment: Edited the answer for you last question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be like so

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.table, .content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.table {
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #bbb;
}

.content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.text {
  min-height: 2000px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
  
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="text">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Go ahead, fill both rectangles with either text or content, see how it works !

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! The sample did work!

Comment: No problem, and since you asked for an horizontal solution, simply replace flex-direction with a column, and all the heights with widths !

Comment: Will it work both way? Horizontal plus vertical scrolling with fixed header and fixed columns this way?

Comment: Sure, you can do both at the same time, just replace `overflow-y` with `overflow` in the `content` class !

Comment: I will try but my guess would be the the frozen columns will not scroll  together with rest when scrolling vertically