# IE 11 equivalent for position sticky for headers in multiple tables

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, position

I have an issue with material tables actually, but I think it is a problem with other tables also.

Don't know why but position sticky is not working in fiddle, so I didn't include it, but on my solution it works perfectly in Chrome Browser.

So, what I need:

1. I have couple of tables (2-4) which should have vertical-x scroll visible every time. It should not go out of screen;
2. All headers should be fixed to top while scrolling y axis;
3. I have some data above the tables so some viewport should be in place;
4. Of course this should be working in IE, because in Chrome it is working with position: sticky as I mentioned.

Please, help. I can't make one table from multiple ones and struggling wih this already for couple days.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/genyklemberg/n5s8h3mj/7/

CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
html {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 25px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;    
}
thead tr {
  position: sticky;
}
thead, tbody {
    display: block;
}
td, th {
    min-width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    border: dashed 1px lightblue;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div>
  <h2>Another div here</h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
          <th>Four</th>
          <th>Five</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAA</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
          <th>Four</th>
          <th>Five</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
          <th>Four</th>
          <th>Five</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Row 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Row 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
            <td>Row 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
            <td>Row 7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
            <td>Row 8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
            <td>Row 9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
            <td>Row 10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I saw this answer [Fixed header table with horizontal scrollbar and vertical scrollbar on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on/18902869#18902869) but couldn't figure out how it could be implemented for multiple tables scroll. Its better also to have VanillaJS answer if some script is needed.