# Fixed Header that allows Horizontal and Vertical Scroll for React

Tags: css

I currently have a data table that I would like to have horizontal, vertical scrolling, and a fixed header. For columns I have between 15-20 and for the rows I would like to show up wards to 50 at a time. Right now I am using Bootstrap4 and React.

### Issues I have come across in some solutions:

- requiring fixed columns (I would like to auto-size columns)
- relying on a jQuery plug-in (for various reasons I would like to avoid mixing jQuery and React)
- detaching the header works for horizontal scroll, but not for vertical scroll
- Using table-layout:fixed resizes all the columns to the same widths

#### This is what I've tried so far:

```
tbody {
display:block;
height:200px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

thead {
display:table;
width:98.7%;
table-layout:fixed;
}

tbody tr {
display:table;
width:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
```

I've tried looking for a solution in this previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on)

Comment: which ones are you trying to  stick ? alike this one  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WVXPNP or that one  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/abboqbR ? (columns can be any size).

Comment: In terms of scrolling I am aiming for something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/3vzrunkt/