# Fixed html table header while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have the following table structure:

```
<table>   
<thead>   
    <tr>   
        <th colspan="4">Current</th>   
        <th colspan="4">New/Requested</th>   
    </tr>   
    <tr>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">RSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  
        <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">CRD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  
        <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Action</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Reason</th>   
        <th nowrap="nowrap">Action Code Status </th>   
    </tr> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>  
            <td></td>   
            .....plenty of rows
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</thead>   
</table>
```

I am trying to fix the header so that if I scroll down it stays visible.
I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486576/frozen-table-header-inside-scrollable-div) but couldn't understand it. How can I do this?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put

Comment: but my table body is not scrollable,i want this when i scroll the page not table body

Comment: still i am playing with this...

Comment: @Vivek - have you tried solution............are you working in which browser ?

Comment: @Vivek - try the jquery plug and do accept ans if it works for you]

Comment: @Pranay- i don't want to do it wd plugin...i want to do it with either css or jquery(in shorter and smarter way).

Comment: @Vivek - plug is made using jquery only............thre is no other rocket science to develop plug in

Comment: yeah i know but there is lots of code in that plug which would not be in use in my case.....

Comment: hi @pranay- look at my code..which i have written in order to do the same..

Comment: possible duplicate of [freeze table header in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591453/freeze-table-header-in-jquery)

Comment: @TechZen-yes!..somewhat it's duplicate  but the context of question is different...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written the following code in order to achieve my goal (as asked in question)-

Here is the plugin i have written.

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.scrollbarTable = function (i) {
       var o = {};
       if (typeof (i) == 'number') o.height = i;
       else if (typeof (i) == 'object') o = i;
       else if (typeof (i) == 'undefined') o = {
           height: 300
       }
       return this.each(function () {
           var $t = $(this);
           var w = $t.width();
           $t.width(w - function (width) {
               var parent, child;
               if (width === undefined) {
                   parent = $('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:auto"><div style="height:50px;"></div></div>').appendTo('body');
                   child = parent.children();
                   width = child.innerWidth() - child.height(99).innerWidth();
                   parent.remove();
               }
               return width;
           }());
           var cols = [];
           var tableCols = [];
           $t.find('thead th,thead td').each(function () {
               cols.push($(this).width());
           });
           $t.find('tr:eq(1) th,thead td').each(function () {
               tableCols.push($(this).width());
           });
           var $firstRow = $t.clone();
           $firstRow.find('tbody').remove();
           $t.find('thead').remove();
           $t.before($firstRow);
           $firstRow.find('thead th,thead td').each(function (i) {
               $(this).attr('width', cols[i]);
           });
           $t.find('tr:first th,tr:first td').each(function (i) {
               $(this).attr('width', tableCols[i]);
           });
           var $wrap = $('<div>');
           $wrap.css({
               width: w,
               height: o.height,
               overflow: 'auto'
           });
           $t.wrap($wrap);
       })
   };
}(jQuery));
```

**How to use:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table#tabss').scrollbarTable();
}
```

hope it will help someone somewhere..

Any way thanks to all of you for your kind support... :)

Comment: yeah...we have to wait for two days to accept own answer...that's y i took time to accept this. :)

Comment: Same question as Sreekesh Okky, what is table#tabss?

Comment: @Vivek What is #tabss?

Comment: tabss is table ID

Answer (score 0):

try this approach but it may not be the best way

```
<table style="top: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 1; background-color: White">   
    <tr>   
      <th colspan="4">Current</th>   
      <th colspan="4">New/Requested</th>   
    </tr>    
    <tr>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">RSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  
    <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">CRD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>  
    <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Action</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Reason</th>   
    <th nowrap="nowrap">Action Code Status </th>   
</tr> 
</table>
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>   
        .....plenty of rows
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

what I did is just created another table for header and gave it fixed position

Answer (score 0):

Using css

```
.fixhead
{ 
    position:relative
    overflow:auto;
}
```

And call this class in  or in gridview headerrowstyle tag.

Answer (score 0):

CSS PART----

```
 <style type="text/css">
    thead tr { position:relative; 
               top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop); 
             }

  </style>
```

HTML PART----

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <td width="1%"></td>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Name</td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    //////////code
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    ////////code
    </tfott>
  </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: sorry I am new on this forum so dont have any idea how to paste the code in answers.Please dont mind this.

Answer (score 0):

Set overflow: auto in the tbody's css.

Answer (score 0):

so I had to create a similar component for my work. (**Note:** admittedly I did this with jQuery but it can still be accomplished without it.)

The solution i came up with was similar and i thought i'd share it as it is much simplier

http://jsfiddle.net/YYaFr/6/

Basically you wrap the `table` in a `div`, copy it (the table) and make the first one just a header table (by removing the `tbody`) and position it absolute.

```
<div class="containerdiv">
    <table class="headerTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col /> * number of columns
             ....
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
             <th></th>
             ....
        </thead>
    </table>
    <table class="dataTable">
        <colgroup>
            <col /> * number of columns
             ....
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
             <th></th>
             ....
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <td></td>
             ....
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the css

```
div.containerDiv
{
    height: 300px; // Whatever height you need. can be set inline if you wish
}
div.containerDiv table.headerTable
{
    position: absolute;
}
div.containerDiv table.dataTable thead
{
    visibility: hidden; // This gives the header table room so it doesn't hide the first row.
}
```

Then the JavaScript basically creates the `colgroups` (or you can generate them server-side if you need.) Sets the widths and viola. That seems a lot simpler in my head so go ahead and check out the jsfiddle.

Comment: hmm...it seems to good approach..but as i saw in ur fiddle..header border and cell border is not lining up..so disturbing the shape of table...let  me know how would you like to fix this problem.

Comment: @Vivek tested in Chrome and IE8 it lines up. What Browser are you using?

Comment: @vivek i just tested in Firefox and its not aligned. Something to do with the way it calculates width? the code where it creates the col element and sets its width it adds 6 pixels for the margins/border in chrome/Ie this is 6 in Firefox it is 5.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm late to the party, but the [jQuery Fixed Table Header Plugin](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx) by Mustafa OZCAN is fantastic.  Just include it, as well as jQuery itself, and set it to work on your table like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#YourTable').fixedtableheader(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Replace `#YourTable` with the ID of your HTML table, and the plugin does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, how I envy people who get to use jQuery. I created a pure javascript and CSS solution for those who are prevented by application limitations from loading a library.

Basically, CSS positions the table and table header row, and tricks the table into behaving like divs. Then javascript manipulates the CSS positioning of the table header row and a "mask" div that hides the moving rows as the table scrolls up (an improvement would be to modify the javascript to detect collision and hide rows that scroll up past the header).

The weakness of this approach is that you now have to set the widths for all the columns.

The relevant components are:

```
<!-- divs with IDs are manipulated with javascript -->
<div class="fixedTableHolder">

  <div class="maskHolder">
     <div id="mask" class="mask">&nbsp;</mask>
  </div>

  <div class="fixedTable">
    <div id="theTable" class="theTable">

       <!-- here is the table, header row must have an ID -->
       <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5"> 
          <tr id="thFixed" class="thFixed"> 
            <td class="col1">Header cell 1</td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">regular cell</td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo in jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/deborah/Msvvr/

Answer (score 0):

Well, hoping someone will be reading this, and save some time with it :)
My goal was to make a small(as small as possible) js, that will take tableID , and put headers as fixed.
It differs from what is given here with that it recalculates width with window.resize, so it allows tables to be resized dynamically, and no fixed sizes used from the start. And in theory - suppose to work with any table... (that was my case...)

```
function HeadsUp()
{
    var headers = $("#TheGrid tr").first();
    headers.css("margin-top", ((headers.height()+1)*-1)+"px");//edit +1 with what you want...
    headers.css("position", "absolute");
}

function ResizeHeaders()
{
    var grid = $("#TheGrid");
    var headers = $("#TheGrid tr").first();
    var firstdatarow = $("#TheGrid tr:nth-child(2)");
    headers.width(grid.width());

    var s = firstdatarow.children("td");
    var d = headers.children("th");//replace with td if you use it there
    for(i=0; i<s.length; i+=1) {
        d[i].width = s[i].clientWidth;
    }
}

$(function () {
HeadsUp();
ResizeHeaders();
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
ResizeHeaders();
});
```

Comment: And if someone needs this stuff in SharePoint, as I did, replace last binding of $(window).resize()
with
SP.UI.Workspace.add_resized(ResizeHeaders);

Answer (score 0):

The best option which worked for me is adding the following css properties to the **th** class in stylesheet.

```
th 
{
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0px;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: it will freeze the header