# How to fix header of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to freeze table header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534284/how-to-freeze-table-header)

I am having a table which is getting populated through ajax call, having fallowing structure-

```
<table>    
    <thead>        
        <tr>            
            <th colspan="4">Current</th>            
            <th colspan="4">New/Requested</th>        
        </tr>        
        <tr>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">RSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>           
            <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">CRD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">CRSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>           
            <th nowrap="nowrap">MSD &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Open QTY &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Action</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Reason</th>            
            <th nowrap="nowrap">Action Code Status </th>        
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <tbody>         
        <tr>             
            <td></td>              
            <td></td>                
            .....plenty of rows        
        </tr>     
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

I am trying to freeze the header of this table..
**Note:** I want to do it on page scroll not table body scroll.
I tried it in all the way as suggested in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534284/how-to-freeze-table-header) post, but nothing seems to work for me...
Any ne one have some different approach or some working example that would be a great help for me.

**jsFiddle of problem**  :  http://jsfiddle.net/UX6Sk/

Comment: why some-one downvoted this question

Comment: Beacause they want to feel !important (pun intended) by voting.

Answer (score 4):

you can find it right here
[Fix the header](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/page/jQuery-Fixed-Table-Header-Plugin.aspx)

AND demo from here 
[Demo is here](http://www.mustafaozcan.net/en/demo/fixedtableheader/jquery-fixedtableheader-demo-en.html)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit buggy, but if you set background-color for thead, this will hide bugs.
Also, made with css-only: http://jsfiddle.net/HErQH/

Comment: when i used `position:fixed` , my thead went outside of page

Comment: Yes, because i'm duplicating header to save the table layout, nut you can hide the fake header, like this [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/wA5kF/)

Comment: it's not working in my page..i don't know whats going wrong...ohhh god...

Comment: Can you give me the link to your page, where it fails?

Comment: it's a on development server..so it's not accessible on web. :(