# jqgrid fixed column header and fixed footers

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I was looking to fix the jqgrid column header and fixed footers. When there are other items along with jqgrid with data I was looking at fixing the header so that the user knows at all the time what he is looking at.

[Here is the sample for what I am looking for](http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xthf-demo.php)

Note that here I am looking at browsers scroll bar.
Does jqgrid support this?

**Edit**

As JQGrid is html table after all, I tried to use [jQuery TH Float Plugin](http://rommelsantor.com/jquery/thfloat/).
Now it turns out that JqGrid is made of three tables
One for the header, one for the data and the other for the footer. So it seems that I either have to modify thfloat to accommodate this or come up with something else...

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534284/fixed-html-table-header-while-scrolling) solve your situation or give you ideas towards solving it?

Comment: I have got some idea from JQuery TH Float Plugin. It seems that as I have to deal with three table I will have to customize the plugin or come up with something of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough nut to crack.

I got it working by 
First css override the default which is overflow:hidden to

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sdiv{overflow:visible;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv{overflow:visible;}
```

On the javascript JQuery came to my rescue I implemented the following

```
function screenBottom() {
    return $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
}     
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var dataTableTop = dataTable.offset().top;
        var dataTableHeight = dataTableTop + dataTable.outerHeight();
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowBottom = screenBottom();
        //Scroll down         
        if (windowTop > dataTableTop - headerTable.height()
                && windowTop < (dataTableHeight - headerTable.height())) {
            headerTable.offset({ top: windowTop, left: headerTable.offset().left });
        }
        //For footer
        if (windowBottom > dataTable.offset().top + footerTable.outerHeight()
                && windowBottom < dataTableHeight + footerTable.outerHeight()) {
            footerTable.offset({ top: windowBottom - footerTable.outerHeight(), left: footerTable.offset().left });
        }
        //Re adjust of the movement is too fast
        if (windowTop < (dataTableTop - headerTable.height())
            && dataTableTop < (headerTable.offset().top + headerTable.height())) {
            headerTable.offset({ top: dataTable.offset().top - headerTable.height(), left: headerTable.offset().left });
        }
        if (windowBottom > dataTableHeight + footerTable.outerHeight()) {
            footerTable.offset({ top: dataTableHeight, left: footerTable.offset().left });
        }

    });
```

And then to check the footer and header while resizing the window

```
        $(window).resize(function () {
            setInitializeHeadersAndFootersPosition();
        });
function setInitializeHeadersAndFootersPosition() {
            var dataTableTop = dataTable.offset().top;
            var dataTableHeight = dataTableTop + dataTable.outerHeight();
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var windowBottom = screenBottom();
            if (windowBottom > dataTableTop && windowBottom < dataTableHeight) {
                footerTable.offset({ top: windowBottom - footerTable.outerHeight(), left: footerTable.offset().left });
            }
            if (footerTable.offset().top < dataTableHeight && windowBottom > dataTableHeight) {
                footerTable.offset({ top: dataTableHeight, left: footerTable.offset().left });
            }
            if (windowTop > dataTableTop && windowTop < dataTableHeight) {
                headerTable.offset({ top: windowTop, left: headerTable.offset().left }); //Header does not need the offset
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd mention how to populate the missing vars.

```
//grid = $("#yourGrid").jqGrid( ...

dataTable = $(grid[0].grid.bDiv);
footerTable = $(grid[0].grid.sDiv);
headerTable = $(grid[0].grid.hDiv);
//my header column was behind the grid
headerTable.css('z-index', '1000');
setInitializeHeadersAndFootersPosition();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sarath, what a great solution, helped me a lot.  I've expanded on your work, so that the header will only "bounce" once, when it first gets scrolled off the page / repositioned.  Afterward the position gets switched to fixed, but there all a lot of other elements that need compensation.  Enjoy!

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var _grid = $('#jqGrid');  // jqgrid name
    var dataTable = $(_grid[0].grid.bDiv);
    var headerTable = $(_grid[0].grid.hDiv);
    var dataTableTop = dataTable.offset().top;
    var dataTableHeight = dataTableTop + dataTable.outerHeight();
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var headerTablePosition = headerTable[0].style.position;

    //Scroll down         
    if (windowTop > dataTableTop - headerTable.height() && windowTop < (dataTableHeight - headerTable.height()) && headerTablePosition != "fixed")
    {
        var leftOffset = headerTable.offset().left + 'px';  // grab the offset before changing postition
        $(dataTable).css("top", (headerTable.height()+1) + "px");  // +1 to account for the border width of the header
        headerTable[0].style.position = "fixed";
        headerTable[0].style.top = "0px";
        headerTable[0].style.left = leftOffset;
        dataTable[0].style.height = "auto";
        $($(_grid[0].grid.sDiv)).css("top", (headerTable.height() + 1) + "px");  // footer table, +1 to account for the border width of the header
        var gridHeightString = $('#gview_jqGrid').css("height").replace("px", "");
        var newGridHeight = parseInt(gridHeightString) + headerTable.height() + 1;  // +1 to account for the border width of the header
        $("#gview_jqGrid").css("height", newGridHeight + "px"); //outermost grid element
    }
    //Scroll up
    else if (windowTop < (dataTableTop - headerTable.height()) && headerTablePosition == "fixed") 
    {
        headerTable[0].style.left = "0px";
        headerTable[0].style.position = "relative";
        $(dataTable).css("top", "0px");  
        $($(_grid[0].grid.sDiv)).css("top", "0px");  // footer table
        $("#gview_jqGrid").css("height", "100%");  //outermost grid element
    }
});
```