# GridView : How to make fixed Header Row

Tags: asp.net

**?**

Need fixed Header Row from Vertical Scroll bar, because my GridView is very large.

Making 2 panels was my the best try (but also won't works) :

**added :**

```
      <asp:Panel style="width:720px;" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
      <asp:GridView ID="GV3" runat="server" />          
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="justfortest" Text="11111" runat="server" />
      <hr />
      <asp:Panel style="max-height:400px;border-style: outset; border-width: 4px; " 
              ID=HGix runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            .........................
            </asp:GridView>

       </asp:Panel>
       </asp:Panel>
```

***why the horizontal line adds to second panel, it's ScrollBars="Vertical" but works as Both***

Comment: I think you are missing the overflow css setting on the panel. Try overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:auto.
Also you dont need two panels, just one can get the job done.

Comment: @ Aseem Gautam overflow-y and x works only for some browsers, or not ?

Comment: The overflow property is supported in all major browsers.

Comment: yes , but not with -x and -y , as I know ... also WebDev shows error on overflow-x . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implementing a Fixed GridView Header in ASP.NET (Uses Panels)](http://www.shareknowledges.com/57/section-ASPNET/Implementing-a-Fixed-GridView-Header-in-ASPNET.aspx/111)

[Using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=255)

Stackoverflow

[Freezing gridview header in a fixed width div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263333/freezing-gridview-header-in-a-fixed-width-div)
[Table - fixed header, scrollable body, most robust/simple solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301049/table-fixed-header-scrollable-body-most-robust-simple-solution)