# IE8 Fixed Header, scrollable GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know this topic has been asked, but the posts are all out of date, or not functional on IE8.

In brief we basically want to do the excel style locking of column headers in a GridView.

I have seen a couple of solutions one jquery+ css(setExpression) which doesn't work in IE8. And another that uses ajax extensions, yet again doesn't work in IE8.

I have been through every solution in the below link and have yet to find a working implementation for IE8.

[GridView : How to make fixed Header Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205271/gridview-how-to-make-fixed-header-row)

I see [telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/frozencolumns/defaultcs.aspx) has an implementation that is more thank what i want, this is such a simple concept I can believe i am going to have to buy a toolkit...

Comment: @Nix do you like a jQuery solution that use Javascript ?

Comment: @Nix perhaps I am missing something here, but does not the GridView render on the browser as an html table? (thus I am puzzled as to why you resist information on table layouts)  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Right but i am not coding the tables.  I am letting server generate them, maybe I** am missing something?  but the solutions you sent me dont work when you are letting asp generate tables.

Comment: Take a look at this scrollable table for some ideas: http://www.webtoolkit.info/scrollable-html-table.html

Comment: sorry @Mark code for webtoolkit.scrollabletable.js doesn't work with IE8 because set expression.

Comment: I am using IE8, albeit in compatibility mode due to other reasons, and it seems to work, just an FYI. (I have no interest in that site btw, just trying to help :)

Comment: So you are saying you are using a GridView, and the solution that leverages the webtookit?  and it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the depths of the internet, the only* implementation that I found is by IdeaSparks.    It provides an opensource custom GridView implementation that allows:

1. Display fix column headers, footer and pager
2. Supports scrollable content
3. User-resizeable column widths (New!)
4. Maintains scroll position and column widths after a postback or callback (New!)

My only complaint is that it requires you to use fixed columns...

Answer (score 2):

This is a [solution](http://fixedheadertable.com/) that its working on ie8 - at least on my ie8.

Here are some demos:
http://fixedheadertable.com/livedemos/

And here is one more with source code http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=255

And one more (good idea) http://datawebcontrols.com/demos/ScrollableDataGridFixedHeader.aspx

Comment: " FixedHeaderTable.com" is using html tables not asp GridViews, and i have tried dotnetcurry and it did not work.  Looking at the last now.

Comment: Why are you dead set on using a gridview instead of an html table? I would think you'd want to go with the web standard...

Comment: I am using ASP.NET there is no reason to use Tables.

Comment: @Matrym You comment suggest that he reinvent the wheel. That is not logical nor helpful.